# iOS Simulator Crash requestAlwaysAuthorization()

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

My code is included below. It's a class intended to return the current location coordinates. The only output I get is "before after before after" - the print lines surrounding requestAlwaysAuthorization. And then the App crashes. The request dialog sometimes shows briefly, sometimes for a few seconds. On few occasions I even get to press "OK". The App always crashes. I've had this problem in xCode 7.0 and now xCode 7.0.1, iOS 9.0 in both cases. I have searched StackOverflow high and low, and most questions on this topic are for earlier versions of both xCode and iOS, and none of the posted solutions helped in my case. Hence, this question. I've also found YouTube tutorials that do basically what I'm doing, but no joy. I also have NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in my plist, and I have Privacy - Location Usage Description and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription for good measure. I have also tried sending a location from xCode via the Product\Scheme menu, and I have also tried using the simulator's Debug\Location. I've tried a few different location options for each. The simulator's Map app always seems to work. And Apple's LocateMe (written in Objective C) also works. Swift 2 (my code below) fails.

```
import CoreLocation

class TheCurrentLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var latitude: Double = 0
    var longitude: Double = 0
    var locationStatus: NSString = "Not Started"

    func initialize() {

        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        print("before")
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
//        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        print("after")

    } // END: initialize()

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print("ERRORS: " + error.localizedDescription )

    } // END: locationManager delegate didFailWithError

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print ("ta da")
        self.latitude = center.latitude
        self.longitude = center.longitude

    } // END: locationManager delegate didUpdateLocations

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        var isAllowed = false

        switch status {
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
            locationStatus = "Restricted Access to Location"
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
            locationStatus = "User Denied Access to Location"
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
            locationStatus = "Location Status Not Determined"
        default:
            locationStatus = "Allowed Access to Location"
            isAllowed = true
        } // END switch status

        if (isAllowed == true) {
            NSLog(String(locationStatus))
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            NSLog(String(locationStatus))
        }

    } // END: locationManager delegate didChangeAuthorizationStatus

} // END: theCurrentLocation
```

Comment: Update your question with details about the crash. Where does it crash and what is the complete and exact error message?

Comment: There is no error message. I wish I could tell you more. There is no other output apart from the print lines already described.

Comment: @RobWelan In Xcode, when your app crashes, you can get a backtrace that reports the error for the crash by typing `bt` at the `(lldb)` prompt in the debugger.

Comment: Fails at the line "0x22888 <+104>:  movl   $0x0, (%esp)". This line brings up the "Always Allow Location" dialog. And then BOOM, crash. I tried to add more log info but I ran into a character limit. Is there a way in StackOverflow to add more (in case anyone requests it)?

Comment: @DanielZhang bt does not seem to work. Once the crash has occurred, there's no more debug prompt. (I'm a bit of a noob - I might be missing something obvious).

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what may be causing it. You cant have both NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription. Only one of them. I think I ran into this problem before. Try to remove one of them and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Why are you telling the user to add this key when their question states they have both. Update your answer.

Comment: @mn1: I have removed the WhenInUsage and the Privacy items in my plist (see my original problem post for full name of each). Has not helped unfortunately.